# C# - parameterizing a generic list at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

Lets say I want to create a List and feed that into something, but T isn't known at compile time and only at run time. What can I do to parameterize T easily? i.e. List<example.GetType()>. Can I do something like this without using MakeGenericMethod?

Edit: List< object > doesn't work as it causes too many boxing/unboxing operations. List will be stored in a dictionary which sits as a field in another class.

Comment: You can make a `List<object>`. But really, do you really need to put _any_ type in there? What's your use case?

Comment: Ah right - I should've said List<object> doesn't work because it causes too many boxing operations. It's just reading a CSV file with lots of different value types, with each column potentially having bool/double/int/etc. Different csv files will be fed in so columns arent necessarily consistent but the main types will be. List stores the values that are in the rows, could also use a dictionary<row#, T> as well.

Comment: `List<example.GetType()>` <-- No cannot be done easily (and specifically, you must use a compile time type between the brackets, not a runtime evaluated type using reflection, which is what you are attempting to do here).

Comment: @Dragnipur Right, so each list is a row, so that list has heterogenous types... so you'd still have to box everything to object. Instead of using a list, why not make a class with a property for each column?

Comment: List doesn't box things to object though? Arraylist will automatically do that but List<T> does not. The rows are not heterogeneous as I'm iterating through by column. So a list of rows is every single row (or in this case I guess cell is a better word) in a single column with each column being a single type.

Comment: If you have a _known_ amount of value types, you can pattern-match on them and return the right list with known type

Comment: For the `too many boxing/unboxing operations` - just want to make sure, have you already actually tested that approach with these csv files?

Comment: Depending on file it's about 250k-500k boxing operations

Comment: I read the discussion above but still kinda unclear about the whole design. Usually when I approach this kind of problem, I design a `List<TRow>`, where `TRow` being a class that contains all the columns (`bool`, `int`, `string`...). Thus a `List<TRow>` becomes essentially a table. If there are many different types of tables that isn't totally random, design corresponding `TRow`s. If you want to support more, you can add a module where future users can input the types of columns in the csv they want to process (schema). There are also goodies like `Npoi.Mapper` on github.

Comment: Yeah I have a row class that has dictionaries for object, int, bool, and double. Since it can't determine the type at runtime it has to initialize all 4 dictionaries<column name, row data> for every row. Then it has a class above it called TableData that has List<Row> and IEnumerable<string> Columns. Just seems like there should be a better way to do this, initializing 4 different dictionaries of different types in the row class seems inefficient, although relatively its much less memory than storing everything in List<object>. Dictionary is used as null cells aren't stored

Comment: @Dragnipur You have a row class and each instance of the row class has 4 dictionaries? And when you enumerate all the values for a column from all rows, the values are `string`?

Comment: IMHO write a generic method to do as much of the heavy lifting as you can. `DoStuff<T>() => new List<T>(); ....` Then a single `MakeGenericMethod` to call it using reflection.

Comment: @Jonathon No - The Columns enumerable is a list of all the column names, and to iterate through the entire table you just plug the column names into the dictionaries for each row. It does seem like I'll probably have to use MakeGenericMethod - just wanted to see what other options were out there. Thanks all!

Comment: I try to avoid using reflection in general and especially when performance is important. But there may not be a better choice.

Comment: You can cache the result of `MakeGenericMethod` in a dictionary to speed up repeated calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to store your data in columns rather than rows. This should avoid the need for boxing, but does require the type for all values in a column to be identical. Something like

```
public class Table
{
    private Dictionary<string, IList> columns { get; } = new();

    public Table()
    {
        columns["bools"] = new List<bool>() {true, false, true};
        columns["ints"] = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    }

    public object GetValue(string columnName, int row) => columns[columnName][row];
    public bool GetBool(string columnName, int row) => ((List<bool>)columns[columnName])[row];
    public Type GetColumnType(string columnName) => columns[columnName].GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

If you need a row-type, just let the row refer to the full table. This solution should only require boxing if you use the `GetValue`-method.

Second option would be to just accept boxing. This *will* have some memory and cache locality penalty but for 500k items the penalty should not be to bad. It should still fit inside the L3 cache for a modern processor. Run a performance profiler if you want to check how large the penalty actually is.

If you are storing very large tables, or are just paranoid about boxing, you could consider some exotic solution, like storing values in binary and converting on the fly. Or generate a runtime type for your values. In the end it really depends on how you intend to use the values and how much effort you want to spend at optimization.

But if the goal is higher performance or lower memory usage you should make sure to measure this before doing anything. Spending a week at reducing 500ms to 50ms on something run once a week will probably never pay for itself.